# Odd artifact next to UIActionSheet in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7

My iOS7 app has an odd visual bug in a UIActionSheet. It is shown below. Any thoughts?

[image]

Code:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: Seeing the same thing. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an iOS7 bug to me in drawing of the button layer, can't really think of a solution but aside trying to work out the factors that have caused that to happen

Maybe try a different approach and see if you have some success?

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Done"];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Or maybe set it under `otherButtonTitles`?

It's a strange one but if you can find the cause it might be worth submitting the bug report to apple